# One or two tables for mailing system

Tags: php, sql, email

I know this has been done before somewhat but I would still like to get some consensus. When building an internal mailing system for your website, is there any advantage to have multiple tables to handle the mail. For example, with

```
message_id,
reply_id,
sender_id,
recipient,
subject,
message,
time,
read_status,
```

I seem to be able to handle everything, however, as the project scales, perhaps 2 tables would be better. I am fairly new to this, so I want to  make sure I am not missing some obvious issue that might occur down the line.

Many thanks for looking at this somewhat abstract question.

Comment: What would your second table do?

Comment: Well this is what I thought, but I have read a lot of posts discussing this and suggesting 2 tables......I can't see what the advantage would be. Perhaps this is a bit of a non-question. Your response sort of confirms this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any advantage to have multiple tables to handle the mail.

Simple thing about `tables` is that their usage is directly proportional to the amount of `data` ( *read columns* ) u need to handle in your layout schema...so unless you have a big schema with lots of attributes / columns, then NO, there is no particular advantage of using multiple tables

> as the project scales, perhaps 2 tables would be better.

Project Scales in what sense???

- If the **number of users increase** then existing schema should be able
  to handle it as there is no need to add any new columns
- If there is need to **add new attributes** ( *read columns* ) , then
  i think you should better normalize and set the schema before
  actually    implementing the DB-Schema

If i would implement something for 2nd case, then ( *being a lazy programmer* ) i would put some columns *reserved* in current schema, so that, if needed, i would later rename the column to my needs and put them directly in use.....no need to redesign the schema ( *in contradiction to what i said in 2<sup>nd</sup> bullet point* ) !!

Comment: mind upvoting or accepting the answer which ever u think can be awarded to my answer!! :)